# Errors in WSO2 Retail Banking sample

Tags: mysql, wso2, wso2-integration-studio, wso2-as, wso2-esb

I'm working my way through the WSO2 retail banking example, and I've come across the following issues and errors:

a). Pre-requisites section

I've installed AcitveMQ on my machine and I can't find a 'activemq-core-xxx.jar' file. Where would I find this?  As a fall back where this jar is required I've deployed the 'activemq-all-5.9.0.jar'file.

b). Install and configure WSO2 servers

It's not clear whether this install process requires that the paths of the four servers be added to the Java classpath.

c). Configure WSO2 Application server

the instruction to edit the 'axis2.xml' file lists the wrong folder for this file.  It should be '$AS_HOME/repository/conf/axis2' not '$AS_HOME/repository/conf' as shown in the docs.

d). Configure WSO2 ESB

the instruction to edit the 'axis2.xml' file lists the wrong folder for this file.  It should be '$AS_HOME/repository/conf/axis2' not '$AS_HOME/repository/conf' as shown in the docs.

e). Set up the Customer Database using MySQL.

Seems a bit daft to apply the 'Database' suffix to a MySQL database name!

f). Deploy the Carbon Application project into WSO2 App Server

I'm completely confused by the instructions in this step. If you literally follow the instructions in the sample doc you get to a 'New Server' pop up dialog in Eclipse where the 'next' and 'finish' buttons are disabled.
This is reached When inside Eclipse I try to add a new server and I enter the main folder of the AS server.

Answer (score 0):

I just hit the same problem as you have in your (a).

The wso2 documentation quotes a specific version, as do other examples on the net. As always, examples that quote specific versions rarely last the test of time :)

I find it best in situations like this to investigate the underlying package, in this case ActiveMQ, usually going backwards through the release documentation, starting at the current version. This revealed that activemq-core was replaced in 5.8 with activemq-client and activemq-broker as per this link

http://activemq.apache.org/58-migration-guide.html

and going forward from that discovery to the current release, shows those jars still exist, so go with actvemq-client and activemq-broker ;)

Answer (score 0):

If you encounter any issue following this sample, please follow the webinar conducted on the same sample at [1](http://wso2.com/library/webinars/2012/05/enterprise-use-case-application-development-using-wso2-developer-studio/). It will help you to get through the issues you encounter in the sample.

Also as you correctly pointed out there were some issues in paths to config files mentioned in the documentation. We have corrected those issues in the documentation now.

[1](http://wso2.com/library/webinars/2012/05/enterprise-use-case-application-development-using-wso2-developer-studio/). http://wso2.com/library/webinars/2012/05/enterprise-use-case-application-development-using-wso2-developer-studio/

Thanks and Regards,

Harshana